# fckediter removing formatting in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, fckeditor

I am using FCKEditer with codeigniter and when I submit data to database, it remove formatting before submitting data.

for example, if I submit

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">know-how in the field of Water</span>
```

the data store in table will be

```
<span>know-how in the field of Water</span>
```

I have form like below

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="frm" name="frm" class="form_class">

<label id="validateeditor" >Description</label>
                      <?

                $dataf = array(
                              'name'        => 'page_description',
                              'id'          => 'page_description',
                              'toolbarset'  => 'Default',
                              'basepath'    => base_url().'application/plugins/fckeditor/',
                              'width'       => '700',
                              'height'      => '400'
                    );

                echo form_fckeditor( $dataf, @$result['page_description']);
</form>
```

I am using following jquery code to save data in database

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#frm").validationEngine('attach',{
  promptPosition :'centerRight',
  onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
    if(status)
    {
        insert_update();
    }
  }
})

});

function insert_update()
{
var fckvalue = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('page_description').GetXHTML();
$("#page_description").val(fckvalue);
    var formdata = $("#frm").serialize();
         $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '<?php echo site_url(ADMIN_DIR."cms/insert_update"); ?>',
               data: formdata,
               success:function (data){
                    var msg;
                    if(jQuery.trim($("#<?php echo $u_column;?>").val())!='')
                    {
                        msg = "Record Updated Successfully.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg = "Record Inserted Successfully.";
                    }

                    jQuery.noticeAdd({text:msg});
                    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
                    editDialog.dialog("close");
               }
        });
}
</script>
```

I don't know what is wrong but when I save data it remove formatting as above.

Comment: stop performing xss filtering when you get the value of the field in controller. You shoud not set the second parameter of `$this->input->post()` to `true`.

Comment: no its not like that my post is like $this->input->post('page_description',false);  but its still same

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as a result of XSS filtering on your input.

Here are a few things you should check to ensure this field doesn't get cleaned:

1. You might have a validation rule filtering the input: `$this->form_validation->set_rules('page_description', 'Description', 'required|xss_clean');`
2. Check if `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` in your `config.php` file.
3. Your input will be filtered if you pass `TRUE` as a second parameter on the input: `$this->input->post('page_description', TRUE);`